# Is odd cycles cover NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Schaefer proved that deciding even cycles cover ( 2-factor with even cycles) in cubic graphs is NP-complete. I am interested in the complexity of odd cycles cover in cubic graphs.
Is it  NP-complete? Is it polynomial time solvable?

P.S. Cycle cover is a set of vertex disjoint cycles that cover all nodes such that each vertex is in exactly one cycle.